# Print time in terminal, and update time every 30 seconds

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am writing a discord bot using `discord.py` and python 3.7.  I have a loop that changes the bot's activity, prints out the current time in the terminal and current ping in the terminal every 30 seconds.  But the problem is that it's not printing the updated time.  If I start the bot at 15:23:52, the bot will always print 15:23:52, for the next hours. It doesn't update its time.

```py
import discord, datetime, time
import datetime as DT

time_date_now = DT.datetime.now().strftime('Date: %d-%m-%Y\nTime: %H:%M:%S')

*****

@tasks.loop(seconds=30)
async def change_status():
   await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game(f'Ping: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms'))
   print(time_date_now)
   print(f'Ping: {round(client.latency * 1000)}ms\n---------------------------')
```

How can I update the printed time correctly?

Comment: You're only calculating `time_date_now` once.  Move that line into the task.

Answer (score -1):

The variable `time_date_now` is declared and assigned only once at the start of your script. If you move that *inside* your task, you'll see it working.